# How to store a variable across instances?

Tags: python, azure-functions, python-3.8

I am trying to create a scrolling Azure Function which retrieves index data from an Elasticsearch Cluster. I am using the **_search** and **scroll** API to achieve this and will be doing this on live data. Currently, I've managed to write a local script that sorts the docs by a timestamp field and filters using the **gt** and **lt** query parameters and am retaining the last timestamp used in a file called ***cursor.py***. In my script after each scroll or runtime, I am overwriting this date by using the below code

```
file = open("cursor.py", "w")
file.write(f"# Please use format YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS\nlastPolled = '{lastRowDateOffset}'")
file.close()
```

However, when I try to use this snippet in an Azure Function it doesn't overwrite the file and doesn't throw any error. It then proceeds to pick up the same date on the next runtime. Is there a different way to open and write a file in the same folder as the trigger or if this is not an option, what would be the best approach to have a global variable that I can call and overwrite within an Azure Function?

Comment: Do you test it on local? Your code works fine on my local function.

Comment: I did. The code is wrapped in a ```while 1:``` loop on the next loop the same date ranges are kept. I am reloading the file using **importlib.reload(cursor)**

Comment: @BowmanZhu ah. I double checked this after you stated you could create them. It turns out it is just me being a noob. When Azure Function is running the root folder is one layer above the folder where the **___init___.py** is located so ```open("cursor.py", "w")``` has created my file there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file should be successfully created.

But please notice that the file will not been created in the function folder, it will been created under the function app folder.

This is because the `__init__.py` is not been recognized as a python script, your root folder is function app folder instead of function folder.

If you want to create the file in the specific function folder, please do like below:

`file = open("yourfunctionname/cursor.py", "w")`